# Vuejs v-for remove element

Tags: vue.js, removechild, v-for

I have code like :

```
<div id="files">
  <div v-for="(file, key) in data.files" v-bind:id="key">
    @{{ file }}
    <span v-on:click="removeFile(key)">
      <button>X</button>
    </span>
    <button v-on:click="addFiles()">Add Files</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

File js

```
methods: {
   removeFile(key) {
       var elem = document.getElementById("#" + key);
       elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
       return false;
   }
```

When i clicked button, selected file had been deleted as well but it also returned error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

I tried this way but same problem: file had been removed, with error

```
var parent = document.getElementById("files");
var child = document.getElementById("#" + key);

parent.removeChild(child);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Any idea? Thanks so much!

Comment: This isn't the right way to manage your DOM when using Vue.  You should be maintaining the list via your v-for and you should then modify the data.files array to remove an element from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the content of your `removeFile()` method with this:
(given that the `files` variable is an array)

```
methods: {
   removeFile(key) {
       this.files.splice(key, 1);
   }
```

You can also use the Vue helper for removing items in an array or a property in an object:

```
methods: {
   removeFile(key) {
       this.$delete(this.files, key);
   }
```

Comment: oh tks! I realized that i had stupid mistake. I had a methods like you but i think that this only delete value and can't remove display >.< Tks so much! By the way, do you know why i can't remove element with v-for of vuejs?

Comment: In vue, it is a bad practice to manually delete the element nodes by yourself. You must leave it to vue to handle. What you should do instead is to update your data and then Vue will act according to it. So if you remove one item from your array, vue will then remove the element associated with that item in your view.

Comment: Nice! Now i understand this problem! Tks again!